# How to start a service from App Widget in Android

Tags: android, listview, service, android-appwidget

I am making a home screen App Widget for my Android app. In that App Widget there is a ListView. That ListView has a custom layout which has a TextView & an ImageButton. I am setting a PendingIntent on that ImageButton to start the service as follows:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(MyConstants.MY_EXTRA, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MyColumns.MY_COLUMN_TITLE)));
        intent.setAction(MyConstants.MY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MyImageButton, pendingIntent);
```

in `getViewAt` method of `RemoteViewsFactory`. But on clicking the ImageButton the service does not start.

I have put an intentfilter with MY_ACTION for MyService. And also tried without it which did not make things work.

Anyone knows how to start service on click of a button inside a list view item in home screen App Widget in Android?

Everything works fine i.e. the ListView is populated perfectly from SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the android javadoc

> **public void setOnClickPendingIntent**
>   Equivalent to calling
>   setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener) to launch the
>   provided PendingIntent. When setting the on-click action of items
>   within collections (eg. ListView, StackView etc.), this method will
>   not work. Instead, use {@link
>   RemoteViews#setPendingIntentTemplate(int, PendingIntent) in
>   conjunction with RemoteViews#setOnClickFillInIntent(int, Intent).

In your update method of your AppWidgetProvider you have to add

```
final PendingIntent clickPendingIntentTemplate = PendingIntent.getService...
views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, clickPendingIntentTemplate);
```

and in the getViewAt method of your RemoteViewsFactory :

```
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
fillInIntent.putExtra(...);
views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_list_item, fillInIntent);
```